# If I store an f-string inside a variable inside a for loop, will the variable pick up all the values inside the for loop?

Tags: python

I need to print a "receipt" based on a customer's orders on a text file. But when I execute this, only the last order shows up and not the rest. What should I do?

```
with open("receipt.txt", "w") as file:
        header = '''
        ==
        CODE\t\t\tNAME\t\t\tQUANTITY\t\t\tSUBTOTAL
        '''
        orders_list = sorted(orders_list, key=lambda k: k['code']) 
        
        for order in orders_list:
            order_code = order['code']
            order_name = products[order_code]["name"]
            order_qty = order['qty']            
            order_subtotal = order['subtotal']

            body = f"{order_code}\t\t{order_name}\t\t{order_qty}\t\t\t{order_subtotal}\t\t"

        lower = f'''
        
        Total:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t{total}
        ==
        '''
        
        receipt = header + body + lower
        file.write(receipt)
```

Comment: You overwrite the `body` variable before you have chance to write it

Comment: You overwrite "body" in each iteration. Instead of this you must append the new entry with "+=" or use a list. This is not related to f-strings in particular.

Comment: You can *embed* the old value of `body` in the new value, `body = f"{body}\n..."`. I wouldn't recommend that, though. Build a list in the loop, then use `'\n'.join` to produce a single string from the list after the loop completes.

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite the previous value of `body` on each iteration. You need to initialize it to an empty string and then append to it inside the loop.